# How can I redirect to an entirely new URL using react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm pretty new to react-router-dom and have found my first problem, any help or advice is appreciated. So I'm trying to access a URL of:

`http://localhost:3000/buying/modern-day-flat`

which will work fine if you manually enter it. My main issue is when I'm in my search results component, with a URL of:

`http://localhost:3000/search/Newcastle%20upon%20Tyne,%20UK/54.978252/-1.61778`

When I include a `<Link>` to try to link to the first page(modern-day-flat one):

```
<Link className="displayPicGrid"  to={props.property.fields.for_sale?`buying/${props.property.slug}`:`renting/${props.property.slug}`} >
  <img className="displayPicGrid"  src={props.property.fields.images[0].image}></img>
</Link>
```

It changes the route **from**

`http://localhost:3000/search/Newcastle%20upon%20Tyne,%20UK/54.978252/-1.61778`

**to**

`http://localhost:3000/search/Newcastle%20upon%20Tyne,%20UK/54.978252/buying/modern-day-flat`

It changes the last param of the URL rather than the entire URL. What I'm expecting it to instead go to is:

`http://localhost:3000/buying/modern-day-flat`

I feel I've conceptually missed something and this might be a simple issue, as I can't find anything online about it.

Comment: just use full url: `/buying/modern-day-flat` with a slash on the beginning

Comment: I apologise that is working. I was checking deployed version. Thank you a ton :)